# Integral of a disk automorphism

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $|\alpha|<1$ and $\psi_{\alpha}(z)=(\alpha-z)/(1-\bar\alpha z)$. I want to prove that $$\frac 1 {\pi} \int\int_{\mathbb{D}}|{\psi_{\alpha}}^{'}|dxdy = \frac{1-|\alpha|^2}{|\alpha|^2}\log\frac{1}{1-|\alpha|^2}$$

I calculated ${\psi_\alpha}^{'}(z)=(|\alpha|^2-1)/(1-\bar\alpha z)^2$. I substituted it and use $z=re^{i \theta}$ and need to integrate $1/|1-\bar\alpha re^{i \theta}|^2$ along circle of radius r (fixed). But how can I do this?

Comment: A stupid question: does it not follow from the change of variables formula that the integral is just the area of the disk?

Comment: @Sanchez No, the determinant of the Jacobian is $\lvert {\psi_\alpha}'\rvert^2$

Comment: @DanielFischer, ah! Of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to polars, as mentioned by Daniel Fischer.  The integral over the disk becomes

$$\frac{1-|\alpha|^2}{\pi} \int_0^1 dr \, r \, \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{d\theta}{|1-\bar{\alpha} r e^{i \theta}|^2} $$

Now,

$$|1-\bar{\alpha} r e^{i \theta}|^2 = (1-\bar{\alpha} r e^{i \theta})(1-\alpha r e^{-i \theta})  = 1+|\alpha|^2 r^2 - 2 \alpha_r r \cos{\theta} - 2 \alpha_i r \sin{\theta}$$

where $\alpha_r = \Re{(\alpha)}$ and $\alpha_i=\Im{(\alpha)}$.  The integral over $\theta$ may be done via contour integration and the residue theorem.  Let $z=e^{i \theta}$, then $d\theta=-i dz/z$, $\cos{\theta}=\frac12 (z+z^{-1})$ and $\sin{\theta}=(-i/2) (z-z^{-1})$.  The integral over $\theta$ is then

$$i \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{\alpha r z^2 - (1+|\alpha|^2 r^2) z + \bar{\alpha} r}$$

Because we assume that $|\alpha| \lt 1$, the only pole of the above integrand for which we need compute the residue (i.e., inside the unit disk) is at $z=\bar{\alpha} r$.  The value of the integral above is, by the residue theorem,

$$i 2 \pi \frac{-i}{2 r^2 |\alpha|^2 - 1 - r^2 |\alpha|^2} = \frac{2 \pi}{1-|\alpha|^2 r^2}$$

The integral over the unit disk is then

$$\frac{1-|\alpha|^2}{\pi} 2 \pi \int_0^1 dr \frac{r}{1-|\alpha|^2 r^2}= (1-|\alpha|^2) \int_0^1 \frac{du}{1-|\alpha|^2 u} $$

The sought-after result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, you can assume $0 < \alpha < 1$. Let us call $\rho := \alpha r$. Then

$$\frac{1}{\lvert 1 - \rho e^{i\theta}\rvert^2} = \frac{1}{1+\rho^2 - 2\rho\cos\theta},$$

and you can integrate that using one of the classical methods, like the residue theorem.